# Unexpected promise value in .then()

Tags: node.js, promise

I've just inherited some code and it includes something I've never seen before. After poking around, I haven't found anything that seems to sufficiently explain what I'm seeing.

```
doAThingThatReturnsAPromise()
  .then(currentState => {
    ...
    return token.save({ key1: val1, key2: 'val2' });
  })
  .then(() => {
      console.log(arguments);
  });
```

`token.save()` returns a resolved promise with no value (e.g. `return Promise.resolve()`.

What surprised me is that, in the second `.then()`, `arguments` has a value and it's the value of `currentState`. I've never bumped into that before and haven't found any documentation that indicates that this is the expected situation if an empty resolution is passed.

Can anyone shed some light or point me to the bit of documentation that sets this expectation? Since I didn't expect it, I want to be sure I document it or, if it's some kind of accidental side effect, that I change things around a bit.

Comment: I can't imagine a scenario in which this can happen. However, one possibility could the `arguments` variable is in parent scope of both `currentState` and anonymous function in the second `then()`. It's difficult to say anything without looking at the code surrounding this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal behavior with native JS promises.

```js
Promise.resolve('a')
  .then(function() {
    return Promise.resolve()
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log(arguments)
  })
```

My guess is that `doAThingThatReturnsAPromise()` returns an non-standard promise. Try wrapping it in a `Promise.resolve`:

```
Promise.resolve(doAThingThatReturnsAPromise())
  .then(currentState => {
    ...
    return token.save({ key1: val1, key2: 'val2' });
  })
  .then(() => {
      console.log(arguments);
  });
```

This behavior will probably disappear.